# Facebook image sharing with link and title android

Tags: android

my problem is that i am not able to see content title and content description of my sharing image using facebook share in android app.

my code is

```
if (shareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
                ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                        .setContentTitle("Content Title")
                        .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("shareValue")))
                        .setContentDescription("Content Description")
                        .build();
                shareDialog.show(linkContent);  // Show facebook ShareDialog
            }
```

Comment: please is here somebody who have faced this problem or who have some solution, please share

Answer (score 0):

sharing those parameters has been disabled in Facebook graph API

[Modeling content](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#model)